# MySQL: Show table on update

Tags: mysql

I wanted to know if its possible to display the contents of a mysql table on a page as soon as its contents are changed/updated

Comment: What do you mean? Like an IRQ that calls your webpage to be refreshed?

Comment: You could poll `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name';` and check when the `Update_time` changes.

Comment: What i need to do is show the contents of the table as soon as its contents change.I'm trying to make a new chat system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 conceptual methods for getting data from your server and updating your page accordingly: **PUSH** and **PULL**

The **PULL** method is one in which your page polls the server at a predefined interval to retrieve updated data and update the view accordingly. A search here or on Google for "server polling" or "ajax polling" will likely give you all the info you need to implement this approach.

The **PUSH** method is one in which the server pushes data down to the client (your page) when it is updated. The [Ajax Push Engine (APE)](http://www.ape-project.org/) is a framework for doing data PUSH operations over the web, I'd recommend checking it out if you want more info on this approach.

If you're looking for a more specific answer to your question, you'll need to post more relevant information about your problem, i.e.: server platform, programming language, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm using jQuery and PHP as my programming languages